# What's the best implemention for non-blocking wait/delay for a period of time in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

Currently I need to implement a simple non-blocking delay function in a Windows Store app project. This function should do nothing, just idle for a specific period of time without blocking the UI. 
My question is: how to implement such a function properly? I know this is an old question, but I really have no clue after some search online.

Best wishes!

[Edit]
I've tried this but not work.

```
public static async Task WaitFor(int millisecondsDelay)
{
    var idleTask = Task.Run(() => { Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay); });
    await Task.WhenAny(new Task[] { idleTask });

}
```

Comment: That is the most complicated way to wait I've ever seen! You are so close; just remove almost all that code.

Comment: Yeah, at first I just can't believe it can be done in such a simple way. Obviously the painful experience when implementing the delay/waiting function using threading on Win32 has left some shadow in my heart. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It schedules a task that completes at a future time using timer rather than blocking a thread.

An example that waits 5 seconds and then continues:

```
private async Task DelayThenDoSomeWork()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    // Do something
    var dialog = new MessageDialog("Waiting completed.");
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks mike! I'll do some test on it. It seems much cleaner than many old implementions on Win32.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I want. It's so simple, clean and elegant!The new asynchronous feature of c# really saves lots of pain.I remember how painful it is to implement a non-blocking delay or wait function using threading. The keyword async and await are awesome! Many thanks!

Comment: @SimonFisher: Glad you like them!

Comment: to complement, there's no such class like MessageBox.In stead, just use MessageDialog: var msgDlg = new MessageDialog("OK"); await msgDlg.ShowAsync();

Comment: @SimonFisher Right, not in Windows Store apps at least. Fixed the example.